# What is the term for an array that is not associative?

Tags: arrays, terminology

What is the proper term for the type of array that does not contain textual keys?

That is to say

```
$my_array[0], $my_array[1] etc. vs $my_array['some-key']
```

An 'indexed' array? Is there even such a term for this type?

Comment: Agreed with @Joe. If you're that concerned about the ambiguity, use a [synonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) for "associative array."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply an array, the associative array you are referring to is a language implementation that will use a different underlying data structure and is not even possible in C. By definition when you are referring to an array by index that is all it is.

> In computer science, an array data structure or simply array is a data
>   structure consisting of a collection of elements (values or
>   variables), each identified by at least one index.

-[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure)

Answer (score 0):

Numerical?  Numerically Indexed?  I don't think there's an agreed upon term.  When you retrieve a php array it can be "ASSOC" for associative or "NUM" for numerical.  So that's what I'm guess, someone should know what you mean if you used either of those.

Answer (score 0):

a numerically indexed array: [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/arrays.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just an array, but [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)  uses the term "Numeric Arrays", which would clear up any ambiguity between the two types.